# NSMenu selector in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm at a loss to see why this doesn't work. The menu shows, but is grayed out if I leave `autoenablesItems` at the default, and the actions aren't called if I set it `false`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    // ...
    func action1(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("Urk, action 1")
    }

    func action2(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("Urk, action 2")
    }

    func popUpMenu(#event: NSEvent) {
        var theMenu = NSMenu(title: "Contextual menu")
        theMenu.addItemWithTitle("Action 1", action: Selector("action1:"), keyEquivalent: "")
        theMenu.addItemWithTitle("Action 2", action: Selector("action2:"), keyEquivalent: "")
        //theMenu.autoenablesItems = false
        NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(theMenu, withEvent:event, forView:self.view)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        self.popUpMenu(event: theEvent) // The menu shows
    }
}
```

**Update**

As per @Chuck's answer, you will need to do the following:

```
func popUpMenu(#event: NSEvent) {
    var theMenu = NSMenu(title: "Contextual menu")
    theMenu.addItemWithTitle("Action 1", action: Selector("action1:"), keyEquivalent: "")
    theMenu.addItemWithTitle("Action 2", action: Selector("action2:"), keyEquivalent: "")

    for item: AnyObject in theMenu.itemArray {
        if let menuItem = item as? NSMenuItem {
            menuItem.target = self
        }
    }

    NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(theMenu, withEvent:event, forView:self.view)
}
```

Comment: Where is this code? Are you sure this object is in the responder chain?

Comment: It's in an SKScene, and popUpMenu is called from mouseDown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is that an NSMenuItem created with that method doesn't have a receiver, so it uses the responder chain, and this object is not in the responder chain. You can force it to see your object by setting the menu items' targets to `self`.